# Difference between trim{it <= ' '} and trim in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, trim

trim in kotlin remove space int leading and trailing, but when android studio
convert java code to kotlin ,convert trim() in java to trim{it <= ' '} in kotlin
when change this to trim,It made no difference.
whats difference between trim and trim{it <= ' '}??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html

> fun String.trim(): String
> Returns a string having leading and trailing whitespace removed.

The `it <= ' '` would remove all the 'non printable' characters with [ascii code](https://www.ascii-code.com/) less or equal than space (ascii decimal = 32) as carriage return, line feed...

I've just tested with many of this characters:

```
val kotlin = "\t\t"
println(kotlin)
   
val kotlin2 = "\t\t".trim()
println(kotlin2)
   
val kotlin3 = "\t\t".trim{it <= ' '}
println(kotlin3)
```

this outputs:

They both clean this characters. And as @AlexeyRomanov states kotlin understands as a whitespace character the ones that return true using the [isWhitespace](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-whitespace.html) method. So the `it <= ' '` is to make it only trim the same chars as java does and not the other whitespace characters according to the Unicode standard.

If we test for example the `\u00A0` character:

```
val kotlin4 = "\u00A0\u00A0".trim()
println(kotlin4)
   
val kotlin5 = "\u00A0\u00A0".trim{it <= ' '}
println(kotlin5)
```

we can see the difference in output:

You can test it in the [kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/a9Y9AsNcJ).

Comment: Of course they both remove `\t`, its code is 9 < 32. You need to test with Unicode whitespace characters to see the difference. Or with non-whitespace characters with code < 32 (e.g. "Start of Heading" `\u0001`)

Answer (score 3):

Java's [`trim` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) says

> Otherwise, if there is no character with a code greater than '\u0020' in the string, then a String object representing an empty string is returned.
>
> Otherwise, let k be the index of the first character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020', and let m be the index of the last character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020'. A String object is returned, representing the substring of this string that begins with the character at index k and ends with the character at index m-that is, the result of this.substring(k, m + 1).

So the condition is exactly `{ it <= ' ' }` (where `it` is a character in the string).

Kotlin instead [uses](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/b1fac4e72192f85c31e81c32582eeabe9382816f/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Strings.kt#L114)

```
public fun CharSequence.trim(): CharSequence = trim(Char::isWhitespace)
```

which is true e.g. for non-breaking space `\u00A0`, Ogham space mark `\u1680`, etc. and false for some characters below `' '` (e.g. `\u0001`).